# What would be a good implementation of iota_n (missing algorithm from the STL)

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, c++11, iota

With C++11, the STL has now a `std::iota` function (see a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)). In contrast to `std::fill_n`, `std::generate_n`, there is no `std::iota_n`, however. What would be a good implementation for that? A direct loop (alternative 1) or delegation to `std::generate_n` with a simple lambda expression (alternative 2)?

**Alternative 1)**

```
template<class OutputIterator, class Size, class T>
OutputIterator iota_n(OutputIterator first, Size n, T value)
{
        while (n--)
                *first++ = value++;
        return first;
}
```

**Alternative 2)**

```
template<class OutputIterator, class Size, class T>
OutputIterator iota_n(OutputIterator first, Size n, T value)
{
        return std::generate_n(first, n, [&](){ return value++; });
}
```

Would both alternatives generate equivalent code with optimizing compilers?

**UPDATE**: incorporated the excellent point of @Marc Mutz to also return the iterator at its destination point. This is also how [`std::generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) got updated in C++11 compared to C++98.

Comment: I think this question focuses on something too specific for something more general: the different loop constructs.

Comment: Why don't you try it and compare the assembler?

Comment: @KerrekSB Not that much of an expert on grokking assembly output. I'm interested in hearing from people with such expertise if STL oneliners with lambdas will normally be optimized to straight loops. If it is the case, this would be a bigger incentive to write more variations on STL algorithms, rather than thinking hard about intricate loops.

Comment: If you wanted to work with random access iterators only, you could simply do `std::iota(start, start + n, value);`. Also, I would change `i != n` to `i < n` for the first alternative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a random example, I compiled the following code with `g++ -S -O2 -masm=intel` (GCC 4.7.1, x86_32):

```
void fill_it_up(int n, int * p, int val)
{
    asm volatile("DEBUG1");
    iota_n(p, n, val);
    asm volatile("DEBUG2");
    iota_m(p, n, val);
    asm volatile("DEBUG3");
    for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) { *p++ = val++; }
    asm volatile("DEBUG4");
}
```

Here `iota_n` is the first version and `iota_m` the second. The assembly is in all three cases this:

```
    test    edi, edi
    jle .L4
    mov edx, eax
    neg edx
    lea ebx, [esi+edx*4]
    mov edx, eax
    lea ebp, [edi+eax]
    .p2align 4,,7
    .p2align 3
.L9:
    lea ecx, [edx+1]
    cmp ecx, ebp
    mov DWORD PTR [ebx-4+ecx*4], edx
    mov edx, ecx
    jne .L9
```

With `-O3`, the three versions are also very similar, but a *lot* longer (using conditional moves and `punpcklqdq` and such like).

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer. Regardless of what `punpcklqdq` does, (I checked on MSDN), it's reassuring to know that there is hardly any abstraction penalty from calling `std::generate_n` + a lambda.

Answer (score 3):

You're so focused on code generation that you forgot to get the interface right.

You correctly require `OutputIterator`, but what happens if you want to call it a second time?

```
list<double> list(2 * N);
iota_n(list.begin(), N, 0);
// umm...
iota_n(list.begin() + N, N, 0); // doesn't compile!
iota_n(list.rbegin(), N, 0); // works, but create 0..N,N-1..0, not 0..N,0..N
auto it = list.begin();
std::advance(it, N);
iota_n(it, N, 0); // works, but ... yuck and ... slow (O(N))
```

inside `iota_n`, you still know where you are, but you've thrown that information away, so the caller cannot get at it in constant time.

General principle: don't throw away useful information.

```
template <typename OutputIterator, typename SizeType, typename ValueType>
auto iota_n(OutputIterator dest, SizeType N, ValueType value) {
    while (N) {
        *dest = value;
        ++dest;
        ++value;
        --N;
    }
    // now, what do we know that the caller might not know?
    // N? No, it's zero.
    // value? Maybe, but it's just his value + his N
    // dest? Definitely. Caller cannot easily compute his dest + his N (O(N))
    //       So, return it:
    return dest;
}
```

With this definition, the above example becomes simply:

```
list<double> list(2 * N);
auto it = iota_n(list.begin(), N, 0);
auto end = iota_n(it, N, 0);
assert(end == list.end());
```

Comment: Nice point, I agree that both the existing `iota` and the putative `iota_n` should return the destination.

Comment: @TemplateRex: `iota` doesn't return the destination because it's equal to its second argument. But `iota_n` is different, the end point is implicit, and thus `iota_n` does need to return the destination.

Comment: Ah thanks, now I see. I updated the answer with your info. Note that `std::generate_n` also got this upgrade in C++11.

Comment: There's one thing I don't like here, that `N`, which is by convention a macro name, is used as a variable. The rest is very good. In particular, there's no point in obfuscating code using postfix increment magic. Spelling out the assignment and increment operations doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

A hypothetical `iota_n`

`std::iota_n(first, count, value)`

can be replaced by a one liner.

`std::generate_n(first, count, [v=value]()mutable{return v++;})`

I prefer this to have a lingering function that is not in the standard. Having said that, I think a `std::iota_n` should be in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Probably use back_insertor along with std::generate_n so that pre-allociton of  collections can be avoided.

```
vector<int> v3;
generate_n(back_inserter(v3),10,[i=1]() mutable{
    return i++;
});
```

We can swap this for iota_n till we get iota_n :)