# Set std::vector<int> to a range

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stdvector, iota

What's the best way for setting an `std::vector<int>` to a range, e.g. all numbers between 3 and 16?

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7256008/8331

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You could use [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) if you have C++11 support or are using [the STL](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html):

```
std::vector<int> v(14);
std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 3);
```

or implement your own if not.

If you can use `boost`, then a nice option is [`boost::irange`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html):

```
std::vector<int> v;
boost::push_back(v, boost::irange(3, 17));
```

Comment: `v.reserve(14)` would save on the default initialization.

Comment: @rhalbersma I am not sure that would work. That just changes the internal storage of the vector if necessary, but iota needs a valid iterator range.

Comment: Not if you use a `std::back_inserter`

Comment: @rhalbersma and then when would `iota` stop? There is no way of telling it "stop after N numbers".

Comment: Your code is fine, but I would prefer my own `iota_n` answer to do the up front memory reservation, rather than default initialization 0...0 and then immediately overwriting with 3...16. What if N = 14 billion in stead of 14?

Comment: @rhalbersma I agree. An option is to use boost::irange.

Answer (score 26):

```
std::vector<int> myVec;
for( int i = 3; i <= 16; i++ )
    myVec.push_back( i );
```

Comment: +1 for KISS. Yours is also the only answer (so far) that you can clearly see the range in the code (loop from 3 to 16 inclusive). The others all use 3 (start of range) and 14 (number of elements).

Comment: Doing a `myVec.reserve(14)` upfront would be even better here.

Comment: Ah, but that's a bit too simple for *real* C++. Your solution is less than 20 lines long, and won't trigger 30 cryptic template errors with a typo :). It will perform unneeded initialization, though, but I suspect the difference will rarely be felt...

Answer (score 8):

See e.g. this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767512/what-would-be-a-good-implementation-of-iota-n-missing-algorithm-from-the-stl)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template<class OutputIterator, class Size, class Assignable>
void iota_n(OutputIterator first, Size n, Assignable value)
{
        std::generate_n(first, n, [&value]() {
                return value++;
        });
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;                   // no default init
    v.reserve(14);                        // allocate 14 ints
    iota_n(std::back_inserter(v), 14, 3); // fill them with 3...16

    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int const& elem) {
        std::cout << elem << "\n";
    });
    return 0;
}
```

Output on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/QsV15)

Comment: With back_inserter_iterator, you don't need to call reserve, don't you?

Comment: @jrok You don't need to, but it's more efficient. `back_inserter` will call `push_back`, but if you insert a large amount of elements, `push_back` will in turn do a lot of reallocations.

Comment: @jrok you never need to call reserve. It's only ever used to avoid reallocations.

Answer (score 2):

std::iota - is useful, but it requires iterator, before creation vector, .... so I take own solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<int ... > struct seq{ typedef seq type;};

template< typename I, typename J> struct add;
template< int...I, int ...J>
struct add< seq<I...>, seq<J...> > : seq<I..., (J+sizeof...(I)) ... >{};


template< int N>
struct make_seq : add< typename make_seq<N/2>::type, 
                       typename make_seq<N-N/2>::type > {};

template<> struct make_seq<0>{ typedef seq<> type; };
template<> struct make_seq<1>{ typedef seq<0> type; };


template<int start, int step , int ... I>
std::initializer_list<int> range_impl(seq<I... > )
{
    return { (start + I*step) ...};
}

template<int start, int finish, int step = 1>
std::initializer_list<int> range()
{ 
    return range_impl<start, step>(typename make_seq< 1+ (finish - start )/step >::type {} ); 
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vrange { range<3, 16>( )} ;

    for(auto x : vrange)std::cout << x << ' ';

}


Output:

  3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

Comment: The cryptic part of this example would go in a .h file somewhere that you wouldn't look at often, if ever. I think the use of `range<3, 16>()` reads nicer than using `std::iota`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `std::generate`. It can generate values for a container based on a formula

```
std::vector<int> v(size);
std::generate(v.begin(),v.end(),[n=0]()mutable{return n++;});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since C++ 23, [`ranges::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/iota) can be used.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
int main() {
    int start = 3, end = 16;
    std::vector<int> v(end - start + 1); // initialize with 14 zeros
    std::ranges::iota(v, start); // fill with consecutive integers starting from 3
    // v={3,4,5,...,3+14-1}
}
```

Alternatively, to add elements starting from an empty `vector`, `ranges::generate_n` can be used (since C++ 20) in conjunction with a `back_inserter`.

The following example also can be easily modified to use a different step than 1.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream> // only used for output in this example
int main() {
    int start = 3, end = 16;
    int len = end - start + 1;
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(len); // allocate enough space for elements
    std::ranges::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), len, 
           [i=start]() mutable {return i++;});
    std::ranges::copy(v, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ")); // output
}
```

Comment: Great update! Thanks for keeping this page up-to-date!