# Shortest Way For Storing Multiple Values In An Array

Tags: c++

I am very certain that I saw the syntax for what I want to do on this website a while ago, but I cannot find it anymore and I forgot what it was. Say I wanted to store the values from 1 to a 100 in an array. What would be the syntax without using a loop. I remember the syntax being something like this:

```
int line [] = {1 .. 100};
```

What is the correct syntax?

UPDATE: I figured out what I meant by this question. What I read a while ago was the syntax to have all the elements in an array equal to a number. For example, in a GCC compiler, you can set all the elements in an array equal to zero like this:

```
int line [10] = {[0 ... 9] = 0};
```

By doing this, all the elements in the array will be equal to 0. It is a very useful thing to know in my opinion and much easier than using a for-loop.

Comment: _"I remember the syntax being something like this"_ That might be a compiler extension, or you have seen some _pseudo code_, but that's not standard c++ IIRC.

Comment: Using [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set std::vector<int> to a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965732/set-stdvectorint-to-a-range)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

const int line[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };